# image merging using php in GD

Tags: php, image, gd

I want to merge two images but the problem is one image is in `.PNG` format and the second one is in `.JPG` format. The output should be in the `.PNG` format but the transparency is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [ImageSaveAlpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php)() and [ImageAlphaBlending](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php)() documentation and comments.